# CK editor image uploading is not working in production with rails 5 app + carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, image-uploading

I am working with CK editor and after deploying I'm not able to upload any images but it was working in development. I get this error "image source url is missing" and here is my config.js file :

I found a lot having the same error but no one answered why this is happening so should I migrate to another editor or what?!

[config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3xBK.png)

```
I, [2018-02-02T12:48:12.886841 #16570]  INFO -- : [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d]   Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f51110b4668 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20180202-16570-1g62x7e.jpg>, @original_filename="ibrahim.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"ibrahim.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "ckCsrfToken"=>"7n2JrWACJV1ceGDYnu1SUaY1p9iWr0Q4P0b40nQv", "CKEditor"=>"post_content", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"en"}
    I, [2018-02-02T12:48:12.892512 #16570]  INFO -- : [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    F, [2018-02-02T12:48:12.895003 #16570] FATAL -- : [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d]
    F, [2018-02-02T12:48:12.895093 #16570] FATAL -- : [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d] MiniMagick::Error (ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed):
    F, [2018-02-02T12:48:12.895128 #16570] FATAL -- : [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d]
    F, [2018-02-02T12:48:12.895216 #16570] FATAL -- : [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d] mini_magick (4.8.0) lib/mini_magick/configuration.rb:127:in `cli'
    [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d] mini_magick (4.8.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:38:in `graphicsmagick?'
    [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d] mini_magick (4.8.0) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:126:in `executable'
    [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d] mini_magick (4.8.0) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:110:in `command'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, could you upload an image and give an inspection, to see where it's looking? he's probably looking in one folder and you're set to look elsewhere. And did you precompile your assets in production mode?

I have this config in my app:

```
/* Filebrowser routes */
// The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

// The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

// The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

// The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

// The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

// The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

// The location of a script that handles file uploads.
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
```

in your config / initializers / ckeditor, did you uncomment anything? And in your config / application.rb, did you put something like this?

```
config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets
    config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* ckeditor_assets/* *.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif img/*)
    config.encoding = "utf-8"
    config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/*"
    config.autoload_paths += %w(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)
```

Well, can you post more details? Are you using which to upload carrierwave or paperclip, or something else?

Comment: I'm using carrierwave

Comment: I user carrierwave. 

first of all I didn't uncomment anything in the config but this line is uncommented on its own:  require 'ckeditor/orm/active_record' 

secondly, I don't have the lines you mentioned in application.rb

thirdly, I don't know how to precompile in production.

Comment: I have not had a very good experience with the carrierwave, but ok.
First, go to config/initializers/ckeditor and uncomment line 12 and line 22, which talks about image extensions and file extensions.
Second, in your config/application.rb place the above my code on precompile.
Third, how to precompile, when you will upload your app, before `rails s` put `rails assets:precompile && rails s`

Comment: And also, in config/initializers/assets put this: `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/*)` , before precompiling and starting the server.

Comment: I did all that but still, I get the error image source url is missing. line 42 configure the url of the assets coming from ck editor. should I uncomment that?!

Comment: Could you please put what the logs return when it gives the error?

Comment: And no, this line apparently would not need to be uncommented.

Comment: Okay, there is a folder in your app called log, probably if you uploaded your application in production mode it will have a file called production.log where everything happens from the requisitions and answers appears there. It will probably be a big file, but go to the end and look for something related to the ckeditor or the carrierwave. copy and paste in your question, not here not comment. to make it easier to see.

Comment: Okay I added it in the question

Comment: Thanks a lot to your help man, as I read the production.log I found that I need to install ImageMagick so I installed it on my server and now it works. you saved my day man,  thanks

Comment: Ok, take a look at this line: 
`F, [2018-02-02T12:48:12.895093 #16570] FATAL -- : [5a150ff6-afb3-4f98-a1cb-c954703b971d] MiniMagick::Error (ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed):`
did you put a `gem 'mini_magick'` in your gemfile and run `bundle install`?